# Error core.hpp..no when install gem ruby-opencv on ruby 2.3.0 and linux 16.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, opencv

I install opencv I try to install gem `ruby-opencv`
when `bundle install` then error

```
>> Check the required libraries...
checking for main() in -lstdc++... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_calib3d... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_contrib... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_core... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_features2d... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_flann... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_highgui... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_imgproc... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_legacy... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_ml... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_objdetect... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_video... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_photo... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_gpu... yes
checking for main() in -lopencv_nonfree... no
opencv_nonfree not found.
>> Check the required headers...
checking for opencv2/core/core_c.h... yes
checking for opencv2/core/core.hpp... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

I try to read log file `mkmk.log`

> ---
>
> have_header: checking for opencv2/core/core.hpp...
>   -------------------- no
>
> "gcc -E
>   -I/home/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-linux -I/home/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/home/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include/opencv2/include     -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wno-maybe-uninitialized  -fPIC  conftest.c -o conftest.i" In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:48:0,
>                    from conftest.c:3: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:49:4: error: #error core.hpp
>   header must be compiled as C++  #  error core.hpp header must be
>   compiled as C++
>       ^ In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54:0,
>                    from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:48,
>                    from conftest.c:3: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:49:4: error: #error base.hpp
>   header must be compiled as C++  #  error base.hpp header must be
>   compiled as C++
>       ^ In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54:0,
>                    from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:48,
>                    from conftest.c:3: /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:54:19: fatal error: climits:
>   No such file or directory compilation terminated. checked program was:
>   /* begin */ 1: #include "ruby.h" 2:  3: #include
>    /* end */
>
> ---

I use `ruby 2.3.0` on `ubuntu 16.04`.

Can anyone tell me the way to fix this essue?

Tks for any supports.